# Rename a Role in the Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

How do you rename the name of a role in the SecurityData dataworkspace in Lightswitch?

```
//Lookup the role, and rename it, or create one if none exist.
var rolesQuery = this.DataWorkspace.SecurityData.Roles.Where(r => r.Name.StartsWith(oldRoleNameString)).Execute();
Role role = rolesQuery.Any() ? rolesQuery.Single() : this.DataWorkspace.SecurityData.Roles.AddNew();
role.Name = "OtherName";
```

An InvalidOperationException is thrown that states "Cannot set the value of the property 'Name' because it is read-only."

So what is the correct way to do this then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming roles is not possible.  There's a couple reasons for this:
1. LightSwitch bases the role implementation on ASP.NET's Membership/Role system which doesn't provide an API to rename roles.
2. The Name property cannot be updated because it is the primary key and LightSwitch doesn't allow changing the values of primary keys.

Instead, you'd need to delete the role and add a new one to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in asp.net roles are referenced by name even though in the underlying data model the table asp_net_Roles uses a GUID column as primary key:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[aspnet_Roles]    Script Date: 26.01.2015 13:56:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Roles](
    [ApplicationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()),
    [RoleName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [LoweredRoleName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_aspnet_Roles_RoleId] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [RoleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Roles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_aspnet_Roles_ApplicationId_aspnet_Applications_ApplicationId] FOREIGN KEY([ApplicationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[aspnet_Applications] ([ApplicationId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Roles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_aspnet_Roles_ApplicationId_aspnet_Applications_ApplicationId]
GO
```

TOO BAD!